# On the injection of exactly two artificial variables into the Phase I of a two-phase simplex

Tags: linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

I am relatively new still to linear optimization and as I understand it, the two phase method is a common practice for finding the bfs before using the simplex or a simplex like solver (a solver relying on an initial bfs). I am using [this document](http://optlab.mcmaster.ca/feng/4O03/Two.Phase.Simplex.pdf) as a resource to understand how to construct a phase I, but I am getting doubts that the author has provided all the information needed.

I'll skip to the standard form of the problem which is as follows

\begin{align*}
\text{max } & 2x_1 &+ 3x_2 &+ x_3 & \\
\end{align*}

Subject to

\begin{align*}
           &x_1   & +x_2  & +x_3 & +x_4 &      &     & =40\\
          2&x_1 & + x_2 & -x_3 &      & -x_5 &     & =10\\
           &      & -x_2  & +x_3 &      &      &-x_6 & =10\\
\end{align*}

Where

\begin{align*}
x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6\geq0
\end{align*}

We can see that we have 3 constraints and yet we only add two artificial variables $x_7$ and $x_8$. I believe that 2 artificial variables are always sufficient because it is explained that if $x_7+x_8=0$ then both independently equal 0.

The author doesn't state that two is sufficient but I believe it is what he is implying. Is this the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & =40\\
2x_1 + x_2− x_3 − x_5 & =10\\
−x_2 + x_3− x_6 & =10
\end{align*}

Solve all three equations for $x_4$, $x_5$, and $x_6$ after setting $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$.
Now,
\begin{align*}
x_4 & = 40\\
-x_5 & = 10\\
-x_6 & = 10.
\end{align*}

So we need only two artificial variables for the negative slack variables.